# how to install gcore on RHEL 7

Tags: linux, rhel7

After upgrading to RHEL 7 (a re-install) of my server, i can't locate gcore neither crash-gcore-command package is available.

Can some one pls help me to know how to install gcore on RHEL 7

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Did you try installing `gdb`?

`yum install gdb`